# Frequencies of stellar g-mode oscillations in astroseismology

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, astrophysics, stellar-physics

It's a simple derivation that in a gravitating fluid, if the density decreases with height then a perturbed fluid element should oscillate at the [Brunt-Vaisala Frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brunt%E2%80%93V%C3%A4is%C3%A4l%C3%A4_frequency),
$$N^2 = - \frac{g}{\rho_0} \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial z}.$$

It is often stated in astroseismology literature (e.g. [1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.6407.pdf), [2](https://www.s.u-tokyo.ac.jp/en/utrip/archive/2011/pdf/15Anna.pdf), [3](http://www.astro.caltech.edu/~jlc/ay101_fall2015/ay101_asteroseismology_25nov2015.pdf)) that "gravity waves up to a frequency N can propagate."  This is also often depicted in figures like the one attached where g-modes are allowed for $\omega < N$.

But if oscillations occur **at the Brunt-Vaisala Frequency** then how can waves be allowed for any frequency **below** the Brunt-Vaisala Frequency?

Additionally, why are g-modes *excluded* when *below* N, but above the [Lamb Frequency ($S_l$)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asteroseismology#Theoretical_background)?

$$S_l^2 = l (l+1) \frac{c_s^2}{r^2}$$

[image]